# Netbeans can't start Glassfish 4 server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish

I am using Netbeans 7.4 and Glassfish 4.0. I can start glassfish 4.0 manually from command line but when i click the run the project button from netbeans it says "Starting GlassFish Server". It became more than 10 minutes but nothing happens. 
It was running fine yesterday, i didn't change anything but today it can't start the server.

What may be the problem?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the server is configured properly in Netbeans? It might be a good idea to try deleting and re-adding it. If the Java you are using is a JDK not just a JRE, then you could use `jps -v` on the command line to show you what Java processes are running before and after you click start. If nothing starts, there's probably a config issue.

Comment: I am sure everything is set properly because it was running fine yesterday.

Comment: @Mike It is a bug probably. 
https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231584

Comment: Are you able to log onto the administrator web interface?

Comment: @Kerry After i started manually, yes i can.

Answer (score 9):

This problem stems in your locale settings but the solution is pretty simple:

In Netbeans installation directory find `netbeans/etc/netbeans.conf file`.
Open & Edit the file using a text editor. Locate ***"netbeans_default_options="*** in the file and add `--locale en` to the end of options.
For example mine looks like:

```
netbeans_default_options="-J-client -J-Xss2m -J-Xms32m -J-XX:PermSize=32m -J-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -J-Dapple.awt.graphics.UseQuartz=true -J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true -J-Dsun.zip.disableMemoryMapping=true --locale en"
```

Now restart Netbeans. If you are still having the same problem, delete and recreate your glassfish domain and it will work.

Comment: How do I "delete and recreate [my] glassfish domain"?